# Hibernate - Foreign and primary keys in inheritance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I was wondering, is it possible to have something like this. Let's say I have a table called `material`:

```
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

On Java side entity would be:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("M")
public class Material extends Expense {

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal price;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

and table called `occupation`:

```
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| payment_type | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price        | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

On Java side entity would be:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("O")
public class Occupation extends Expense {

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal price;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

Now lets say I want to create a common class for an `Occupation` and `Material` called `Expense` on Java side that will represent expenses of materials and occupations. That would look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "expense_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

On SQL side:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| expense_type | varchar(31) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

However, the problem is that primary key of expenses is a foreign key in material and occupation table when we introduce inheritance. Is it possible that expense table has its own primary key and to somehow hold id's and discriminator types for materials and occupations so that material and occupation tables can have rows with same id's (like `34` id in material and `34` id in occupation table)? I mean, on SQL side it can be done quite easy, but what about Java side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to hibernate docs, try:

> The @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns annotations
>   define the primary key(s) of the joined subclass table:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Boat implements Serializable { ... }

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BOAT_ID")
public class AmericaCupClass  extends Boat { ... }
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168

Also look at PrimaryKeyJoinColumn javadoc, it has:

> (Optional) The name of the primary key column of the table being
>   joined to.  Defaults to the same name as the primary key column of
>   the primary table of the superclass (`JOINED` mapping
>   strategy); the same name as the primary key column of the primary
>   table (`SecondaryTable` mapping); or the same name as the
>   primary key column for the table for the referencing entity
>   (`OneToOne` mapping).
>
> String referencedColumnName()

I think it is that what you need

Comment: Nope. That didn't solve an issue. It basically renames id columns in subclasses.

Comment: According to PrimaryKeyJoinColumn javadoc, it has: referencedColumnName: The name of the primary key column of the table being joined to. - try to use it

Comment: This is the solution I used and this is indeed the one that is correct :)

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible since, according to the JPA 2.0 specs. It says in section 2.4 (Primary Keys and Entity Identity):

> The primary key must be defined on the entity class that is the root of the entity hierarchy or on a
>   mapped superclass that is a (direct or indirect) superclass of all entity classes in the entity hierarchy. The
>   primary key must be defined exactly once in an entity hierarchy.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.