# Hibernate/JPA - Is possible to have a children with parent's ID + another field?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I am new using Hibernate and I am trying to know if is possible to change the primary key of a child component with a composite key. This is my parent component:

```
public class Person{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
}
```

This is my child component:

```
public class User extends Person {
   private String email;
   private String password;
}
```

I would like to identify my user with id+email key. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your inherited entities share the same table, it wouldn't be possible, as in the database there can be only one primary key logic per table.

However if you have a inheritance strategy using joins, it would be possible I guess - check out [Hibernate - Foreign and primary keys in inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732180/hibernate-foreign-and-primary-keys-in-inheritance)

Comment: Thank you so much, my inheritance type is "Joined" then i will try. How do you suggest to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: Something like what is discribed in the accepted awnser in the referenced question - @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="email") at the User table. So in the database there should be separate tables with one primary key each.

Comment: This looks like a good tutorial on the topic: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance